# GNU Octave Button

Tags: octave

How do you hide a panel by clicking a button inside?
See code below:

```
f = figure;
p = uipanel ("title", "HELLO WORLD", "position", [.2 .2 .75 .75]);
c = uicontrol ("parent", p, "string", "HELLO.", "position", [150 10 100 20]);
```

What I am looking for is that line that will close the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a callback function for the `uicontrol` that sets the `Visible` property of the `uipanel` to `off` when the button is clicked.

See the documentation on [`uipanel` properties](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Uipanel-Properties.html#Uipanel-Properties)  and [`uicontrol properties](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Uicontrol-Properties.html#Uicontrol-Properties) for more details.